# Adding a class to @Html.Raw helper that uses TempData?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, helper

I suppose the issue is that Html.Raw doesn't have an overload option (which makes sense, since you'd just declare the class in one of the opening tags in the raw html), but also that I have a TempData element to deal with..

Here's what I have (I've tried a few different combinations, with ', ", @, +, etc.):

```
@Html.Raw("<div class='"logout"'>@'"TempData["logoutText"]"'</div>")
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with Html.Raw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@Html.Raw("<div class=\"logout\">" + TempData["logoutText"] + "</div>")
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Neither of Anton's/Reddy's examples worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Raw("<div class='" +logout+"'>'"+ TempData["logoutText"] +"'</div>")
```

If the variable `logout` = "logout"

and `TempData["logoutText"]` = "Click Here To LogOut"

Then the output would be

```
<div class='logout'>'Click Here To LogOut'</div>
```

You can also use a formatter like below

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("<div class='{0}'>{1}</div>",logout, TempData["logoutText"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
@Html.Raw("<div class='" + logout + "'>" + TempData["logoutText"] + "</div>")
```

However a cleaner solution would be:

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("<div class='{0}'>{1}</div>", logout, TempData["logoutText"]))
```